# How to use v-bind in css with Nuxt.js ar Server Side

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I want to have dynamic color scheme to my pages. Based on the url, I send an API request that fetches the color scheme from the database.

For this, I fetch the colors in the nuxtServerInit store hook. I then use `v-bind()` in CSS to dynamically color the components.

For reference, https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html#css-modules.
Ex:

```css
    #main-container {
      max-width: 500px;
      margin: auto;
      background-color: v-bind('designTemplate.backgroundColor');
    }
```

Here, designTemplate is a computed variable that fetches the value from the store.

I am using SSG. On inspection of the generated files, I can see that the colors are not bound to css and the server rendered page does not have the required colors.

In the generated file, I am seeing

`.class-name[data-v-15114cda]{background-color:var(--fec1f67e)}`

But the css variable fec1f7e is not found in the file. Only during hydration is the colors actually applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:
Solved the problem. Used an alternate way of accomplishing my requirement.

Instead of using v-bind in css, I created root level css variables. This was done in the head section of my page.

```js
head() {
 return {
   style: [
        {
          cssText: `
            :root {
              --base-color: ${this.designTemplate.baseColor};
              --background-color: ${this.designTemplate.backgroundColor};
            }
          `,
          type: 'text/css'
        }
      ]
   }
}
```

With this in place, I can access these variables in all my files and style them as:

```css
    #main-container {
      max-width: 500px;
      margin: auto;
      background-color: v-bind('designTemplate.backgroundColor');
    }
```

The css variables are injected in the head of the html and with server side generation, I get a properly colored server rendered page.